# How to edit this javascript ternary function to return nothing if first result is false?

Tags: javascript, ternary

```
function scrollTagsPanel(event) {

    reachedBottom() ? loadMoreTags() : console.log('keep scrolling');

    function reachedBottom() {
        return tagsCol.scrollHeight - tagsCol.scrollTop === tagsCol.offsetHeight;
    }

    function loadMoreTags() {
        console.log('load more...');
    }
}
```

Since `reachedBottom()` will only return if you hit the bottom, I need something to fill in the false part ie: `console.log('keep scrolling');` I tried using `return;` but that threw an error and I can't leave that part blank. And rather not have a an empty function there.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: Don't use the conditional operator for side effects .

Comment: @FelixKling you mean in the return statement? Could you explain? It seems to me that the equation check should be fine in the return, what would the side effects be?

Comment: The conditional operator produces a *value*. You should be doing something with that value, e.g. assign it to a variable, pass it do a function or use it as part of a larger expression. Example: `var result = someCondition() ? someValue : someOtherValue;`. If you don't do anything with the value, then don't use the conditional operator, but `if(...else)`.

Comment: Ah got it... I am using the result as a `truthy` or `falsy` test to trigger or not trigger the next function. Felt I could skip the whole, `if / else return true, false` to save lines of code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use a regular `if` condition, that's what it's for

```
if ( reachedBottom() ) loadMoreTags();
```

Comment: @LeonGaban - most of the time, `if/else` is what is most useful, and readable. Often times, when you need to always return something based on a condition, like say `var x = bool ? 'a' : 'b'`, ternary operators are really neat.

Answer (score 0):

Could use logical `AND` operator `&&`

```
reachedBottom() && loadMoreTags()
```